# How do I edit the moderncvtheme{classic} style? Detailed description below

Tags: tables, fonts, packages, moderncv

How do I remove the lines to the left of both sections, highlight my name in **bold** (default LaTeX) font and add a list of attached documents at the very end *in italics* to the right of the word "Anlagen:" (not in italics) instead of the word "Inhalt"? "Anlagen" should be of the same font size as "Lebenslauf", and "Arbeitszeugnis". Ideally, everything should be centered along a vertical line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{moderncv-additions}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme{classic}   % optional arguments are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
%\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                % idem

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}            % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}  % only for the classic theme, if you want to change the width of your name placeholder (to leave more space for your address details
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{default}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[12pt]{moresize}

\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}           % required when changes are made to page layout lengths

% personal data
\firstname{Joe}
\familyname{Mustermann}
%\title{Resumé title (optional)}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{__}{__}        % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{__}                     % optional, remove the line if not wanted
   %\phone{phone (optional)}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
   %\fax{fax (optional)}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
   \email{__}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
   %\extrainfo{additional information (optional)} % optional, remove the line if not wanted
    \photo[256pt]{picture}                          % '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to and 'picture' is the name of the picture file; optional, remove the line if not wanted

%\nopagenumbers{}                             % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

% color redefinitions must be after \begin{document}!
%\definecolor{firstnamecolor}{RGB}{125,85,85}
\definecolor{firstnamecolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{familynamecolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{quotecolor}{RGB}{125,85,85}
\definecolor{addresscolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{sectionrectanglecolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{sectiontitlecolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{subsectioncolor}{RGB}{125,85,85}
\definecolor{footersymbolcolor}{RGB}{125,85,85} 

\makeatletter

\pagestyle{empty}
%\chapter*{Bewerbungs}{unterlagen}
%\chapter*{Bewerbung als\\}{ XXXXXXX }%\underline{\hspace{3cm}}}
\section{\huge Bewerbung als\\ XXXXXXX \underline{\hspace{3cm}}}

%\vspace*{50mm}
\vspace*{10mm}
\hfill%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=10cm, right}
%   \vspace*{3mm}
\hspace*{5mm}{{\color{firstnamecolor}\includegraphics[width=256pt]{picture}}}\\[3mm]    \centering\familynamestyle{\@firstname}~~\firstnamestyle{\@familyname}  \\
%   \hspace*{5mm}{{\color{firstnamecolor}\includegraphics[width=256pt]{picture}}}\\[3mm]
\@addressstreet, \@addresscity ~~~ \\ 
\mobilesymbol~\@mobile ~~~ \\ 
\emailsymbol~\@email
\end{adjustbox}

%\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
%   \vspace*{3mm}
%\hspace*{5mm}{{\color{firstnamecolor}\includegraphics[width=256pt]{picture}}}\\[3mm]   \familynamestyle{\@firstname}~~\firstnamestyle{\@familyname}    \\
%%  \hspace*{5mm}{{\color{firstnamecolor}\includegraphics[width=256pt]{picture}}}\\[3mm]
%   \@addressstreet, \@addresscity ~~~ \mobilesymbol~\@mobile ~~~ \emailsymbol~\@email
%\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{70pt}

\end{minipage}

\vfill

\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
    \section{\huge Inhalt}
Lebenslauf\\
Arbeitszeugnis\\
%\hrule
%\tableofcontents
%\textbf{\huge Inhalt:}

%\begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
%\item \textit{Lebenslauf}
%\item \textit{Arbeitszeugnis}
%\end{itemize}
%- Lebenslauf
\end{minipage}
%
%\newpage
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\chapter{Curriculum}{~Vit\ae}
%\makequote
%
%\section{Persönliche Daten}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\cvline{Name}{\@firstname~\@familyname}
%\cvline{Anschrift}{\@addressstreet, \@addresscity}
%\cvline{Telefon}{\@mobile}
%\cvline{E-Mail}{\@email}
%\cvline{Geburtsdaten}{1. Januar 1970 in Musterstadt}
%\cvline{Staatsbürgerschaft}{Österreichisch}
%\cvline{Familienstand}{ledig}
%\cvline{Präsenzdienst}{abgeleistet}
%\cvline{Führerschein}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G}
%makeatother 
%
%\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 are optional
%
%\section{Ausbildung} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\cventry{xx/xxxx -- xx/xxxx}{Akadem. Grad}{Institution}{Stadt}{\textit{Abschluss}}{Bemerkung}  % arguments 3 to 6 are optional
%
%\cventry{xx/xxxx -- xx/xxxx}{Akadem. Grad}{Institution}{Stadt}{\textit{Abschluss}}{Bemerkung} 
%
%\section{Berufserfahrung} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\cventry{xx/xxxx -- xx/xxxx}{Musterkaufmann}{Musterfirma}{Musterort}{}{Bemerkung}
%
%\section{Sprachen} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\cvline{Deutsch}{Muttersprache}{}
%\cvline{Englisch}{Verstehen A1, Sprechen B2, Schreiben C3 \hfill {\scriptsize \itshape Europäische Kompetenzstufe}}
%
%\section{IT Kompetenzen} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\cvline{Musterkategorie}{Mustermethode 1 (z.B. mit Musterprogramm 2), Mustermethode 2 (z.B. mit Musterprogramm 4)}
%
%\newpage
%
%\section{Auszeichnungen} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\cvline{xx/xxxx}{Musterpreis}
%
%
%\section{Außeruniversitäre Tätigkeiten} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\cvline{....}{....}
%
%\section{Interessen}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\cvline{....}{....}
%
%\section{Publikationen} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\subsection{Konferenzen und Workshops}
%
%\cvline{mm/jjjj}{Autor 1 und Autor 2. \textbf{Mustertitel: Unser tolles Paper.} In \textit{Proceedings of the First Muster Workshop 1970}, Musterstadt, Musterland, YYYY.}
%
%% \newpage
%
%\subsection{Technical Reports}
%
%\cvline{....}{....}
%
%\cvline{....}{alternativ kann man auch BibTex verwenden:}
%
%\renewcommand*{\refname}{Abschlussarbeiten}
%\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{cv}
%\bibliography{publications}       % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%
%\newpage
%\chapter{Bachelor}{zeugnis}
%\vspace*{1cm}
%\begin{center}
%   % \fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{Bakk-Zeugnis}} 
%\end{center}
%
%\newpage
%\chapter{Master}{zeugnis}
%\vspace*{1cm}
%\begin{center}
%   % \fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{Masterzeugnis}}    
%\end{center}
%
%\vspace*{1cm}
%\begin{center}
%   % \fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{Masterzeugnis-2}}  
%\end{center}
%
%% \newpage
%% \chapter{Abschluss}{zeugnis}
%% \vspace*{1cm}
%% \begin{center}
%%  % \fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{Abschlusszeugnis}} 
%% \end{center}

\end{document}

% end of file `cv_german.tex'
```

Comment: Your code is not complete. Can you paste in the rest?

Comment: Let me add a link for downloading the Zip folder as there are quite a few files that must also be available: https://latex.tugraz.at/_media/vorlagen/bewerbungsmappe.zip

Comment: I remember tinkering with moderncvthemeclassic.sty a bit. As far as I can recall in the end nothing was added or commented out in that file. No other files in the Bewerbungsmappe were modified. The Tex file shown above *is* my file without any personal information.

Comment: Added the comments with the \end{document} part. Thanks for helping with formatting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to get rid off the lines on the first page you need to define an new command `\mysection` like

```
\newcommand*{\mysection}[1]{% <=========================================
  \vspace*{2.5ex}%
  \parbox[m]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\raggedleft\hintfont{\color{sectionrectanglecolor}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0ex}}}% <=========
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
% \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[m]{\maincolumnwidth}{\sectionstyle{#1}}\\[1ex]}
```

With the used `\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0ex}` the rule is gone ...

Your name is already printed in bold (`\mdseries`) because the used font is defined with:

```
\renewcommand*{\firstnamefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\sffamily\mdseries\upshape}
```

## Edited

To be able to get italic text call package `lmodern`, add option `roman` as class option and comment out the wrong line:

```
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{default} % <=================================
```

To add a list of attached documents simply use a `tabular` like this:

```
    \mysection{\huge Anlagen} % <=======================================
\begin{tabular}{p{\hintscolumnwidth}p{\separatorcolumnwidth}l}
  & & \textit{Lebenslauf}\\
  & & \textit{Arbeitszeugnis}
\end{tabular} % <=======================================================
```

So with the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} % <========================

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{moderncv-additions}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme{classic}   % optional arguments are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
%\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                % idem

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}            % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}  % only for the classic theme, if you want to change the width of your name placeholder (to leave more space for your address details
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lmodern} % <================================================
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{default} % <=================================
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[12pt]{moresize}

\newcommand*{\mysection}[1]{% <=========================================
  \vspace*{2.5ex}%
  \parbox[m]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\raggedleft\hintfont{\color{sectionrectanglecolor}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0ex}}}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
% \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[m]{\maincolumnwidth}{\sectionstyle{#1}}\\[1ex]}

%\renewcommand*{\firstnamefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\sffamily\mdseries\upshape}


\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}           % required when changes are made to page layout lengths

% personal data
\firstname{Joe}
\familyname{Mustermann}
%\title{Resumé title (optional)}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{adress1}{address2}        % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{0123456789}                     % optional, remove the line if not wanted
   %\phone{phone (optional)}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
   %\fax{fax (optional)}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
   \email{joe.mustermann@email.de}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
   %\extrainfo{additional information (optional)} % optional, remove the line if not wanted
    \photo[256pt]{picture}                          % '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to and 'picture' is the name of the picture file; optional, remove the line if not wanted

%\nopagenumbers{}                             % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

% color redefinitions must be after \begin{document}!
%\definecolor{firstnamecolor}{RGB}{125,85,85}
\definecolor{firstnamecolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{familynamecolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{quotecolor}{RGB}{125,85,85}
\definecolor{addresscolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{sectionrectanglecolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{sectiontitlecolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{subsectioncolor}{RGB}{125,85,85}
\definecolor{footersymbolcolor}{RGB}{125,85,85} 

\makeatletter

\pagestyle{empty}
%\chapter*{Bewerbungs}{unterlagen}
%\chapter*{Bewerbung als\\}{ XXXXXXX }%\underline{\hspace{3cm}}}
\mysection{\huge Bewerbung als\\ XXXXXXX \underline{\hspace{3cm}}} % <==========================

%\vspace*{50mm}
\vspace*{10mm}
\hfill%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=10cm, right}
%   \vspace*{3mm}
\hspace*{5mm}{{\color{firstnamecolor}\includegraphics[width=256pt]{picture}}}\\[3mm]    \centering\familynamestyle{\@firstname}~~\firstnamestyle{\@familyname}  \\
%   \hspace*{5mm}{{\color{firstnamecolor}\includegraphics[width=256pt]{picture}}}\\[3mm]
\@addressstreet, \@addresscity ~~~ \\ 
\mobilesymbol~\@mobile ~~~ \\ 
\emailsymbol~\@email
\end{adjustbox}

%\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
%   \vspace*{3mm}
%\hspace*{5mm}{{\color{firstnamecolor}\includegraphics[width=256pt]{picture}}}\\[3mm]   \familynamestyle{\@firstname}~~\firstnamestyle{\@familyname}    \\
%%  \hspace*{5mm}{{\color{firstnamecolor}\includegraphics[width=256pt]{picture}}}\\[3mm]
%   \@addressstreet, \@addresscity ~~~ \mobilesymbol~\@mobile ~~~ \emailsymbol~\@email
%\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{70pt}

\end{minipage}

\vfill

\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
    \mysection{\huge Anlagen} % <=======================================
\begin{tabular}{p{\hintscolumnwidth}p{\separatorcolumnwidth}l}
  & & \textit{Lebenslauf}\\
  & & \textit{Arbeitszeugnis}
\end{tabular} % <=======================================================

\end{minipage}
%
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Curriculum}{~Vit\ae}
\makequote

\section{Persönliche Daten}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cvline{Name}{\@firstname~\@familyname}
\cvline{Anschrift}{\@addressstreet, \@addresscity}
\cvline{Telefon}{\@mobile}
\cvline{E-Mail}{\@email}
\cvline{Geburtsdaten}{1. Januar 1970 in Musterstadt}
\cvline{Staatsbürgerschaft}{Österreichisch}
\cvline{Familienstand}{ledig}
\cvline{Präsenzdienst}{abgeleistet}
\cvline{Führerschein}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G}
makeatother 

\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 are optional

\section{Ausbildung} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\cventry{xx/xxxx -- xx/xxxx}{Akadem. Grad}{Institution}{Stadt}{\textit{Abschluss}}{Bemerkung}  % arguments 3 to 6 are optional

\cventry{xx/xxxx -- xx/xxxx}{Akadem. Grad}{Institution}{Stadt}{\textit{Abschluss}}{Bemerkung} 

\section{Berufserfahrung} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\cventry{xx/xxxx -- xx/xxxx}{Musterkaufmann}{Musterfirma}{Musterort}{}{Bemerkung}

\section{Sprachen} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\cvline{Deutsch}{Muttersprache}{}
\cvline{Englisch}{Verstehen A1, Sprechen B2, Schreiben C3 \hfill {\scriptsize \itshape Europäische Kompetenzstufe}}

\section{IT Kompetenzen} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\cvline{Musterkategorie}{Mustermethode 1 (z.B. mit Musterprogramm 2), Mustermethode 2 (z.B. mit Musterprogramm 4)}

\newpage

\section{Auszeichnungen} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\cvline{xx/xxxx}{Musterpreis}


\section{Außeruniversitäre Tätigkeiten} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\cvline{....}{....}

\section{Interessen}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\cvline{....}{....}

\section{Publikationen} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\subsection{Konferenzen und Workshops}

\cvline{mm/jjjj}{Autor 1 und Autor 2. \textbf{Mustertitel: Unser tolles Paper.} In \textit{Proceedings of the First Muster Workshop 1970}, Musterstadt, Musterland, YYYY.}

% \newpage

\subsection{Technical Reports}

\cvline{....}{....}

\cvline{....}{alternativ kann man auch BibTex verwenden:}

\renewcommand*{\refname}{Abschlussarbeiten}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{cv}
\bibliography{publications}       % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\newpage
\chapter{Bachelor}{zeugnis}
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{center}
   % \fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{Bakk-Zeugnis}} 
\end{center}

\newpage
\chapter{Master}{zeugnis}
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{center}
   % \fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{Masterzeugnis}}    
\end{center}

\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{center}
   % \fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{Masterzeugnis-2}}  
\end{center}

% \newpage
% \chapter{Abschluss}{zeugnis}
% \vspace*{1cm}
% \begin{center}
%  % \fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{Abschlusszeugnis}} 
% \end{center}

\end{document}
```

you will get the following first page:

[image]

Just a remark: For me it seems you are heavily missusing an old class. better do not do that! Create your cover page by your own would be easier ...

Comment: Looks alright, but the thing is that I prefer to keep my files separate. That's why I commented out the CV, "Bachelorzeugnis", "Masterzeugnis". In fact, I have separate Tex files for them. For example, my CV is based on a completely different template with another style and formatting. I would prefer to list the attachments after the word Anlagen in italics, but not as a ToC, i.e. without any page numbers. PS "Anlagen" should have the same font size as the listed attachments: CV, Bachelorzeugnis, etc.

Comment: Not exactly what I was asking for (the lmodern font for everything, bold fonts for the section names, italics for the list of attachments), but close enough for me to accept your answer as the solution. Thank you!